# Polymer: setting a property's default value causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, polymer, typeerror

I am trying to set a default value of a Polymer element's property like this:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'list-expenses',

  properties: {
    route: Object,
    startDate: {
        type: String,
        notify: true,
        value: 'setStartDate'
    },
    endDate: {
        type: String,
        notify: true,
        value: 'setEndDate'
    }
  },

  setStartDate: function() {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/expenses");
        ref.orderByChild("sortDate").limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
          return snapshot.val().sortDate;
        });
  },

  setEndDate: function() {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/expenses");
    ref.orderByChild("sortDate").limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      return snapshot.val().sortDate;
    });
  }
```

If I now run the code (using polymer serve), I receive the following output on the browser console:

> polymer.html:1938 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property
>   '_parent_startDate' of undefined

This also happens if I set the value to a fixed string, like e.g.:

```
startDate: {
            type: String,
            notify: true,
            value: '2016-06-05'
        }
```

If a don't specify the value, the code runs without any problems. However of course there is no default value set.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? I use the latest version of polymer (installed yesterday).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** The problem is the context of the Firebase callbacks is not bound to the Polymer instance. There are a few ways to resolve this, but the most straightforward is to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
setStartDate() {
  const ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/expenses");
  ref.orderByChild("sortDate").limitToFirst(1).on("child_added",
  // function(snapshot) {
  (snapshot) => { // <-- use an arrow-function instead
    this.startDate = snapshot.val().sortDate;
  });
},

setEndDate() {
  const ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/expenses");
  ref.orderByChild("sortDate").limitToLast(1).on("child_added",
  // function(snapshot) {
  (snapshot) => { // <-- use an arrow-function instead
    this.endDate = snapshot.val().sortDate;
  });
}
```

---

Note that setting `value` to a function name (i.e., a `string`) would not achieve the effect you're expecting, which is presumably to set the property to the return value of the specified function. Using a `string` here would only set the property value to that string literal.

You should actually be supplying a function that calls your intended function for its return value:

```
properties: {
  ...
  startDate: {
      type: String,
      notify: true,
      value: function() { return this.setStartDate(); }
  },
  endDate: {
      type: String,
      notify: true,
      value: function() { return this.setEndDate(); }
  }
},
```

For reference, here's the [documentation for `value`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties):

> Type: `boolean`, `number`, `string` or `function`.
>
> Default value for the property. If `value` is a function, the function is invoked and the return value is used as the default value of the property. If the default value should be an array or object unique to the instance, create the array or object inside a function. See [Configuring default property values](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configure-values) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used the code you provided, however the error stays the same. Here is the entire code of the element:

http://pastebin.com/V2Zxu9S8